# Dynamically set the minimum range in Cognito

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to set the minimum range for a date field to always be todays date or tomorrows date?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. Currently no, but this is something that we plan to work on in the future. [Here is the card](https://trello.com/c/rIJVd5wf) on Trello.

Answer (score 0):

Calculations are now supported for date fields.  Enter =DateTime.Today or =DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) as the Minimum under field settings to restrict the date.  This will also prevent prior dates from being selected on the calendar.